# F# Fake globbing operator and MSBuild

Tags: f#, f#-fake, f#-fake-5

I'm learning Fake 5 (F# Make) and I'm going through the [Getting Started](https://fake.build/fake-gettingstarted.html) tutorial. When I run the following code I receive an error message : `tryscript.fsx (6,7)-(6,54): Error FS0001: The type 'Fake.IO.IGlobbingPattern' is not compatible with the type 'seq<'a>'`

```
#r "paket: nuget Fake.IO.FileSystem //"
open Fake.IO.Globbing.Operators
let csProjectFiles = !! "src/app/**/*.csproj"

csProjectFiles
    |> Seq.iter (fun x -> printfn "ProjectFile: %s" x)

// for projectFile in csProjectFiles do
//     printfn "F# ProjectFile: %s" projectFile
```

But if I comment out two lines starting at `csProjectFiles |> ...` and uncomment the last two lines I will get the expected output of file names.
According to [documentation](https://fake.build/apidocs/v5/fake-io-globbing-operators.html) and Ionide tooltips the `!!` should return a sequence of file names. Can someone advise me what I might be doing wrong?

P.S. I'm using Fake 5.3.1 installed using `dotnet tool install fake-cli -g`

UPD. I don't have any solution for this issue. It resolved itself after Windows 10 got an update and I removed Nuget package caches in `%HOMEPATH\.nuget`, `%HOMEPATH%\AppData\Local\Nuget`, and deleted `.fake` folder and lock file in the same folder as FAKE script and then reran script again.

If you are still facing similar issue developers ask for extended log `fake -vv run <yourScriptName>.fsx` after you clear all the caches, and archived contents of `%HOMEPATH%\.nuget\packages\netstandard.library` after this run.

Comment: What happens if you add a "nuget Fake.Core.Target //" line to your `#r` directive? I don't know how Fake 5 is divided up into packages, but with a name like `Fake.Core` I'd expect it to be essential to things working right. And the fact that the "nuget Fake.Core.Target //" line appears in every example in the Getting Started tutorial you linked to also suggests that it is an essential part of Fake. Try changing your `#r` to the one seen [in this section of the guide](https://fake.build/fake-gettingstarted.html#Cleaning-the-last-build-output) and see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: @rmunn, Adding `Fake.Core.Target` doesn't help. I get the same error message. I first encountered this issue while trying out examples from the Get Started page and when they failed, I created this minimal example, using code from documentation.

Comment: I do not have proper tooling with me now - does composition (`csProjectFiles >> Seq.iter`) instead of pipe (`csProjectFiles |> Seq.iter`) make a difference?

Comment: @psfinaki, I tried function composition operator `>>` and got a different error: `This expression was expected to have type ''a -> 'b' but here has type 'Fake.IO.IGlobbingPattern'`

Comment: Looking at [the `GlobbingFileSystem.fs` source](https://github.com/fsharp/FAKE/blob/e113e64d49af33b5cc8a8bfae322a3c3c98a5c47/src/app/Fake.IO.FileSystem/GlobbingFileSystem.fs), I see there are some extension methods defined, so you might need to open the appropriate namespace to activate those extension methods. Does opening either the `Fake.IO` or `Fake.IO.Globbing` namespace (or both) help?

Comment: @rmunn, Adding both `Fake.IO` and `Fake.IO.Globbing` doesn't resolve the errors mentioned above. And Ionide shows these references as unnecessary.

Comment: How specifically are you running the script? Through `fake` or `dotnet fake`? I.e., what is the command line that you type to run it, including parameters if any?

Comment: @rmunn, Assuming my script is called `tryscript.fsx`, I use `fake run .\tryscript.fsx` to run it. There is no command called `dotnet-fake` to run it as `dotnet fake run .\tryscript.fsx`.

Comment: Since you've installed it via `dotnet tool install fake -g`, you should be able to have a `dotnet fake` command as well via adding `<DotNetCliToolReference Include="dotnet-fake" Version="5.*" />` to your .fsproj file. See [here](https://github.com/FakeBuild/fake-bootstrap/blob/master/dotnet-fake.csproj) for an example. Also, what do you get when you run `fake --version`? I'm pretty stumped at this point; all I can think of is that you somehow have an older version of FAKE installed somewhere on your PATH and that's causing the issue. That's probably not it, but it's one more thing to check.

Comment: Here is a `fake --version` output:
`FAKE 5 - F# Make (5.3.1)
FakePath: <HomePath>\.dotnet\tools\.store\fake-cli\5.3.1\fake-cli\5.3.1\tools\netcoreapp2.1\any\Fake.Runtime.dll`
I definitely don't have a `dotnet-fake` installed. Could it be that files from old _Fake-Calculator_ solution somehow interfere with with latest Fake?

Comment: Upd. Using _Fake-Calculator_ solution is not an issue. Just tried slightly modified version of the script in the new folder. `for` loop works, but `Seq.iter` does not. I think I'll go file an issue in Fake github.

Comment: I can't repro this on macOS. Copy / pasted the code into a new script and ran it, it prints the project files in that directory. I'm sure it's just a typo, as what you've written wouldn't install - but it's `dotnet tool install fake-cli -g` to be able to use `fake` globally.

Comment: @CharlesMager, Thanks for comment. Yes that is a typo. I archived my example in https://github.com/gkalnytskyi/TryFSharpMake, so that FAKE developers could analyze the issue. But I think, you have already seen it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for completeness sake, the reported issue can be found here: https://github.com/fsharp/FAKE/issues/2062

If anyone encounters this issue please open a new issue (and link the old one) and provide the following information:

> Can you clean everything and send the output of fake -vv run tryscript.fsx and attach the logfile? Something is indeed fishy with the NetStandard.Library package
>
> Can you also compress and attach the folder C:\Users\.nuget\packages\netstandard.library and then try to delete it (and again create a logfile for that)?

I'd assume this was either a caching issue or an F# compiler bug or both.